# Which one is correct "et al.’s" or "et al."?

Tags: adverbs, possessives

I want to use the possessive noun form with *et al*.
as in

**et al.'s** versus **et al.**

Comment: If you want answers to this question, you are going to have to rephrase it so that it makes sense in English. As it is now, it is utterly incomprehensible.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet You are correct. I tried answering, and am uncertain if I interpreted the question correctly. I would like to link to your comment as corroboration, to support my statement that writing like this will confuse everyone. You, me and your up voters comprise "everyone".

Comment: You can say *"the paper of Einstein et al."* You can say *"Einstein, Podolsky, and Rosen's paper"*.  Even though  *"Einstein et al.'s paper"* is the grammatically proper form, I don't think you should use it as it looks informal and rather strange to me.

Comment: Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo.

Comment: You'd say either *A et al.'s* or *A et aliarum/aliorum*.

Comment: I've attempted to make the OP's question more intelligible while keeping as close as to the original as possible. But feel free either to roll back or improve it further.

Comment: I think the question is clear enough, just poorly phrased. An example would probably work better, perhaps Peter Shor's example of “Einstein et al.'s paper.”

Comment: In most contexts, the expression should eminently serve the purpose, without the need for the possessive. "The FirstAuthor *et al.* research preceded the publication of the LaterAuthor *et al.* papers.

Comment: Super late to the party and sorry to kick a dead horse...I'm currently in a situation where I want to use the "et al.'s" form because I want to talk about the decade long body of work of a principal researcher that has collaborated with many other researchers. Throughout my thesis proposal I'm citing multiple of her papers and want to conclude with something like "[...] we are combining Bergh et al.'s approach with [...]".

So a form like @PeterShor suggests wouldn't work as it would be 15+ names

Comment: @DanielW: what's wrong with "we are combining the approach of Bergh et al. with ..."? I don't see why you would ever need to use *Bergh et al.'s* rather than *of Bergh et al.*

Comment: Aah damn of course! Classic case of "stared at this for too long". Thanks for the response :)

Comment: Another option is to use *Bergh and his/her/their collaborators' papers* or some other English expression.

Answer (score 31):

The grammatically correct way is *"Einstein et al.'s paper"*, because to indicate possession by a noun phrase in English, the *'s* should be applied to the end of the phrase. However, I don't believe this specific construction is used much, as to me that looks somewhat unusual and feels informal. I'd recommend using a different wording like *"the paper by Einstein et al.", "the paper of Einstein et al."*, or *"Einstein, Podolsky and Rosen's paper"*.

To show that "X et al's paper" is indeed much rarer than "the paper by X et al", consider [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=paper+by+Wang+et+al%2Cpaper+of+Wang+et+al%2Cpaper+by+Anderson+et+al%2Cpaper+of+Anderson+et+al%2Cet+al+%27+s+paper&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=20). Even with the specific names Anderson and Wang substituted for X, "et al's paper" is considerably rarer than *paper by X et al".

Comment: Super late to the party here, but I though I should add that I can't find any mention of the "et al.'s" form in any style guide I have access to (checked about 6), which to me say it's so nonstandard none of them felt it worth bothering to mention.

Comment: Hyper late... but Google Scholar finds over 3 million documents containing the phrase "et al.'s" so it is certainly used in practice. Some of them are even in the titles of much-cited papers from various fields. So... even though our collective gut tells us that it might be unusual and colloquial it seems to be quite common. :)