# Is “et al. [1]” used as a singular or plural subject?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, latin

I've checked out a [similar question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/99886/is-et-al-used-as-a-singular-or-plural-subject), but to the best of my knowledge, it only tells me that "Name et al." is used as a singular subject since it refers to the authors, but what if the “et al..” part is followed by the citation of their article?  I found the following sentence in a journal paper:

> Gomes et al. [7] also outline a greedy method for finding feasible solutions...

So how should I use something like "et al. [1]" in the end? I'm really confused now.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the answer to the question that you cite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Et alii* means "and others", so it would make sense to treat *Gomes and others* as plural. Note that *et al.* is not used for *et alius* ("and another"), since *Gomes et alius* is barely or not at all shorter than *Gomes and Samuel*: it is only used when there are three or more authors in total.

On the other hand, *Gomes et al.* can stand metonymically for *the text by Gomes et al.*, which would be singular; so a case can be made for treating it as singular.

Comment: So both singular and plural usages can be valid depending on context?

Comment: @Mark Singular usage would be rare. It would be for the case where you have a plural subject being treated as a singular, like "Strunk and White says you shouldn't do that", where "Strunk and White" refers to the textbook by that pair of authors rather than to the authors themselves.